# PHP SESSION will not be set by value from DB

Tags: php, html, sql

Problem: I have built an login system and it works fine on my localhost.
Localhost: Here it works.
FTP-server: Here it's not working.

I've tried to fix this for 7 hours now.
`$_POST` is getting the value, if I set a `$_SESSION` it also shows the value.
DB info is correct.

I think the problem is when connecting to DB to get values. Where I did wrong I do not know, as above tried to fix this for a long time now.

Login file:

```
<?php
ini_set("default_charset","iso-8859-1");
session_start();

require_once("db_config.php");
echo $_SESSION['USER_ID']." - ";


if(!empty($_POST['username']) AND !empty($_POST['password'])) {

    $username_db = $_POST['username'];
    $password_db = $_POST['password'];

    if(isset($username_db) AND isset($password_db)) {

        $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        if(!$link) {
            die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
        if(!$db) {

            die("Unable to select database");
        }
        $qry="SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE email='".$username_db."' OR alias='".$username_db."' AND password='".$password_db."' ";

        $result=mysql_query($qry);


        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        while($rows=mysql_fetch_row($result)) {


            $_SESSION['USER_ID'] = $rows['id'];
            header("Location: index.php");
        }

    }

} 

if(!empty($_SESSION['USER_ID'])) {

        $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        if(!$link) {
            die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
        if(!$db) {
            die("Unable to select database");
        }

        $qry="SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id='".$_SESSION['USER_ID']."'";

        $result=mysql_query($qry);
        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            header("Location: index.php");
        }
}


?>
```

**check if login SESSION is set:** I think there is some messed up code here.

```
<?php
ini_set("default_charset","iso-8859-1");
session_start();

require_once("db_config.php");

    if(!empty($_SESSION['USER_ID'])) {
        $user_id = $_SESSION['USER_ID'];

        $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        if(!$link) {
            die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
        if(!$db) {
            die("Unable to select database");
        }

        $qry="SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id='".$user_id."'";

        $result=mysql_query($qry);
        if (!$result) {
            header("Location: login.php");
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $_SESSION['ALIAS'] = $rows['alias'];
            $_SESSION['FIRST_NAME'] = $rows['first_name'];
            $_SESSION['LAST_NAME'] = $rows['last_name'];
            $_SESSION['EMAIL'] = $rows['email'];
            $_SESSION['USER_LEVEL'] = $rows['user_level'];
        }   

    } else { header("Location: login.php"); }


?>
```

Comment: If it works on one system and not another, you have to consider what changed. Are you connecting to a `localhost` DB or by domain? (depending on the host) is `localhost` allowed? Do you have sufficient privileges?

Comment: What's in your `db_config.php` file? What's the value of `DB_HOST`?

Comment: why are you sending a redirect `header` in a `while` loop? (login).. scratch that.. why are you using a `while` loop to get the `userid`?

Comment: What is it outputting? `Failed to connect to server`? Check (by echoing) `DB_HOST`, `DB_NAME` and `DB_PASSWORD` values. Show us the contents of `db_config.php` since it seems to be important to establish the connection to the database. There are a lot of issues with your code, for instance, if `$_POST['username']` is not empty you set `$username_db` as it's value and then check if `$username_db` is set. Why? You just set it. Also, Avoid mysql, it is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: I am connecting to a domain.The only thing I've changed on transfer is db_config.php. And no, I can not give you guys that information. I do not want you guys to connet to the db.

Why I use while loops, do not know. Tried with row and assoc to, I'm used to get sevral values. What should I use instead?

Comment: Why I did $_POST['username'] -> £usernamde_db and check if $username_db is set, I had a sql prevention script where I set $username_db, and if its empty after that it wont be run.

Comment: If you're grabbing only one row, just drop the `while`. The `mysql_fetch_aray` grabs one row. The while is for when you have more than one row to grab. Also, it's good practice to `exit;` after a redirect `header`

Comment: I changed while against if and it started to work. Problem solved :)